# Confused about a dielectric charged sphere in a space with no external Electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, polarization, dielectric

Consider a dielectric sphere with a non-zero density charge on the surface, outside the sphere there is vacuum.
Given the radius and the density, the problem asks to find potential and Electric field inside the sphere, but I got confused: if there is no Electric field outside of the sphere, does it still polarize? Does the external field generated by the surface charge polarize the sphere? How do I actually solve this problem?

Comment: Is polarization necessary for finding the electric field and associating an electric potential to a point inside the sphere? No it isn't.

Comment: I got confused because at first I considered the sphere filled with vacuum, found the associated Electric field and divided by the dielectric constant, and the field was zero inside the sphere. But then I remembered that if the sphere was polarized then It should have a non-zero electric field proportional to the polarization P. So I'm sure I'm having trouble in understanding this situation

Comment: Very related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/288308/confused-about-a-question-about-a-dielectric-sphere?rq=1 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/223896/how-to-find-the-polarization-of-a-dielectric-sphere-with-charged-shell-surroundi?rq=1